# Why does this error occur with my structural equation modeling?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, amos

[image]

When I run this structural equation modeling in amos program, I get the following error message. How do I fix it?
The error message: "The model is probably unidentified. In order to achieve identifiability, it will probably be necessary to impose 4 additional constraints."

I wonder what I should fix in this picture and what constraints I should fix.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the loadings (blue paths) for your single-indicator latent variables L5 and L6 have not been fixed to 1. This may explain the error message. In order to identify the metric (set the scale) of L5 and L6, the loadings of "observed12" and "observed13" must be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for replying my question. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped!